# Matplotlib Multiple Lines Stacking

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 4 .csv files with some raw data (flow rates versus force) and I'm trying to get all 4 lines onto the same graph. I know it's cumbersome, but here's my code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

with open('C:\\Users\\Christopher\\Documents\\School\\2019\\Winter 2019\\ME 360\\Unit 4\\Lab 4\\Raw1.csv', newline='') as csvfile1:
    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile1, delimiter=',')
    for row in readcsv:
        if readcsv.line_num == 1:
            flow1 = row
        if readcsv.line_num == 2:
            force1 = row

with open('C:\\Users\\Christopher\\Documents\\School\\2019\\Winter 2019\\ME 360\\Unit 4\\Lab 4\\Raw2.csv', newline='') as csvfile2:
    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',')
    for row in readcsv:
        if readcsv.line_num == 1:
            flow2 = row
        if readcsv.line_num == 2:
            force2 = row


with open('C:\\Users\\Christopher\\Documents\\School\\2019\\Winter 2019\\ME 360\\Unit 4\\Lab 4\\Raw3.csv', newline='') as csvfile3:
    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile3, delimiter=',')
    for row in readcsv:
        if readcsv.line_num == 1:
            flow3 = row
        if readcsv.line_num == 2:
            force3 = row


with open('C:\\Users\\Christopher\\Documents\\School\\2019\\Winter 2019\\ME 360\\Unit 4\\Lab 4\\Raw4.csv', newline='') as csvfile4:
    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile4, delimiter=',')
    for row in readcsv:
        if readcsv.line_num == 1:
            flow4 = row
        if readcsv.line_num == 2:
            force4 = row


# Change plt font family and text size
plt.rc('font', family='serif', size=10)

# Make the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(5,3))
plt.plot(flow1,force1,'ro--')
plt.plot(flow2,force2,'bs--')
plt.plot(flow3,force3,'g^--')
plt.plot(flow4,force4,'y*--')

# Format the plot
plt.xlabel('Flow Rate (L/min)')
plt.ylabel('Force (N)')
plt.legend(['2.83 mm Nozzle','3.28 mm Nozzle','5.25 mm Nozzle','6.35 mm Nozzle'],loc='lower right')
plt.tight_layout()
#plt.axis([0,10,0,1])
plt.show()
```

And the output, surprisingly, is...
[image: 4 Lines Stacked On Top of Each Other]

How can I get all 4 lines to use the same y axis (flow rate), instead of each line stacking on top of the other?

Comment: Hey Chris, have you tried using `plt.yticks` ?

Comment: Can you post one of the sets of data? Screenshot would suffice

Comment: I think this is the same as always your variables (`flow` and `force`) are lists of strings, but they should be lists of floats. Try something like `flow = list(map(float, row))` for each of your assignments.

Comment: In case you're interested in cleaning up the code, here are some changes to make it more readable: https://ideone.com/vcQ7PJ

Comment: @ThomasKühn Your suggestion worked. Please post it as a solution and I'll accept it.